# PyAutoGui - locate doesn't see the right-click menu

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I have the code below that basically identify the small chrome icon in the windows toolbar, right-click on it using pyautogui and then it should locate the "New Window" option. The problem I face is that, even if I take a screenshot after the right-click, the small menu doesn't show up, making it impossible to locate the "New Window" option.

```
# this part works
chrome_small_icon = r"C:\Users\chrome_small_icon.png"
elem = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(chrome_small_icon)
elem_center = pyautogui.center(elem)
pyautogui.click(elem_center, duration=0.5, button="right")

time.sleep(0.5)
im_after_right_click = pyautogui.screenshot()

# this part finds zero element, reason being, the right-click menu is like a ghost...
chrome_new_window = r"C:\Users\new_window_text.png"
elements = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(chrome_new_window)
```

does anybody have any suggestion about how to locate elements inside the menu that appears when we right click on an element?
Thanks

EDIT
it seems this issue happens only if I right click on the windows toolbar. It does work if I right click on other locations of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to locate the new window text use the keyboard to select the new window option. I just ran the following code on MacOS and I was successfully able to open a new Chrome window:

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.rightClick(pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('chrome.png'))) 
#chrome.png is an image of the chrome icon
pyautogui.typewrite('new window')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```